# Deleting the input directory after files have been processed in a multithreaded environment

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I have an application which runs several threads in two ThreadPoolTaskExecutors. Both executors read inputs from a directory which hosts a list of files and have some classes with @Async methods to process files. How do I safely cleanup the files after the processing has been done? I mean how do I make sure that all threads have been completed and we can clean up the input directory?

Comment: Does each of the threads use all the files?

Comment: @tgdavies No. Each thread reads a different file and persists the data in DB. Also there is no write operation on the files.

Comment: Well then, as @tgdavies hints at, why can the thread not delete each file after processing it?  Would that not remove the need for a specific cleanup operation?

Comment: Take a look at this - https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-batch/delete-archive-files-after-read/